# Regex match any character NOT followed by "? something"

Tags: regex

How can I match a path only if there is no "?" plus zero or more character on the end.

I have the following path:

```
/something/contentimg/coast03.jpg?itok=ABC
```

I want the filename, but only if there is no "?something" after the file extension.

I tried:

```
 /^.*\/(.*)(?!\?.*)$/
```

But it matches anyway. This is the result. What am I doing wrong?

```
Array
(
    [0] => /something/contentimg/coast03.jpg?itok=ABC
    [1] => coast03.jpg?itok=ABC
)
```

Using php.

Comment: unrelated yet helpful hint: when you're grepping a path, you should wrap your pattern with something besides forward-slashes. Then you don't have to escape the slashes, keeping your search pattern more legible: `#^.*/(.*)(?!\?.*)$#`

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^.*\/([^?]+)(?![?].+)$
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://regexr.com?36abv)

Your expression does not work, because `(.*)` matches everything after last `\`, so there is nothing that could be considered as negative lookahead input.

Comment: You can lose the lookahead completely, it doesn't serve any purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url):

```
print_r(parse_url('/something/contentimg/coast03.jpg?itok=ABC'))

(
    [path] => /something/contentimg/coast03.jpg
    [query] => itok=ABC
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*` quantifier behaves greedily and matches everything up to the end of the regular expression, so the negative lookahead kicks in at the end of the input (and of course doesn't find what it's looking for). The regex should be done a little differently:

```
/^.*\/([^?]+)$/
```

This expression matches one or more non-question-mark characters and then asserts that it has reached the end of the input string, which is what you want to do.

Comment: Actually, $ matches end of line, not end of string.

Comment: @pguardiario: Actually neither is technically correct because `$` matches either the end or before a newline that is the last character. You need to explicitly go into multiline mode with `/m` or `PCRE_MULTILINE` for it to match embedded newlines, so IMO the description is OK. I don't want to be "or before an ending newline" pedantic because it serves absolutely no purpose in the context of the answer.

Comment: It's not ok. $ matches end of line. Saying that $ matches end of string is incorrect and I am simply correcting you.

Comment: @pguardiario: As I was saying, **unless you go into multiline mode that's not true**. So let me correct you: "By default, PCRE treats the subject string as consisting of a single "line" of characters (even if it actually contains several newlines)." [From the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). [Here's a live example](http://ideone.com/scGtVl).

Comment: From the link you posted: `...while the "end of line" metacharacter ($)...` - So you can see they agree with me too.

Comment: @pguardiario: Well, I gave you a straight quote from the manual *and* an example program that both agree with what I said. Your quote that "$ matches end of line" remains factually wrong (unfortunately *how it's called* and *what it matches* are different things) and I did my part to prove it; you are free to believe what you want. I hope you enjoyed this exercise in pedantry, because I didn't.

Comment: Fwiw, I can see why if you only use PCRE in non-multiline mode, you might think that end of line is the same thing as end of string, and that someone who points out it's not is being pedantic. It's actually an important distinction though or else I wouldn't have bothered to make it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how it's currently matching:**

`.*` - greedily matches up to before the last `/` - `/something/contentimg`
`\/` - matches `/`
`(.*)` - matches the rest of the string - `coast03.jpg?itok=ABC`
`(?!\?.*)` - checks that the characters following don't match, since we are at the end already, it obviously won't match.

**What you should do:**

It seems like you can just check if a `?` exists in the string, so try:

```
/^(?!.*\?)/
```

Or match up to the last `/`, then check for a `?` from there:

```
/^(?!.*\/.*\?)/
```

**Explanation:**

You already know `(?!...)` is negative look-ahead, you're just not entirely sure how to use it. Wherever you put it, it tries its best to match the given pattern from that position onwards. If it succeeds, the regex doesn't match. So it might be a good idea to put this at the very beginning and try to match the rest of the string.

So the basic format for this example is:

```
/^(?!...).*$/
```

where `(?!...)` contains a pattern for the strings you want to **exclude**.

The `.*$` at the end shouldn't be required, and if you want to check the entire string, remember the `$` at the end of the look-ahead.

```
/^(?!...$)/
```